# migrate laravel table in descending order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I have 5 tables in laravel migration, table sequence is

1. 2017_03_27_121533_create_purchase_solds_table.php
2. 2017_03_27_121533_create_purchases_table.php
3. 2017_03_27_121533_create_purchase_returns_table.php
4. 2017_03_27_121533_create_solds_table.php
5. 2017_03_27_121533_create_purchase_sold_returns_table.php

i migrate it in order of 1,2,3,4,5 and now i want to migrate it descending order like 5,4,3,2,1 so is it possible then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you need to change date and time in the name of each migration:

```
2017_03_27_121531_create_purchase_sold_returns_table.php
2017_03_27_121532_create_purchase_solds_table.php
2017_03_27_121533_create_purchases_table.php
2017_03_27_121534_create_purchase_returns_table.php
2017_03_27_121535_create_solds_table.php
```